# Is the product of two contractible spaces contractible?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

If $X$ and $Y$ are contractible spaces, is $X\times Y$ a contractible space?

Comment: Maybe a more natural question is: does taking products preserve homotopy equivalence?  If you can show that, you can answer your question, and it seems no harder.

Comment: [This suggested edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/64937) - which should have been comment instead - was made to point out that the OP has posted his own answer, which means that he has shown some effort. (But as the question already has some upvotes, I'd say several users have noticed this and voted accordingly.)

Answer (score 4):

$X$ is a contractible space, then we have $H_1:\mathrm{id}_{X}\simeq c_{x}=x_0$.
$Y$ is a contractible space, then we have $H_2:\mathrm{id}_{Y}\simeq c_{y}=y_0$.
Now define $pr_\hat Y:X\times Y\times I\to X\times I$ with $pr_\hat Y(x,y,t)=(x,t)$
and $pr_\hat X:X\times Y\times I\to Y\times I$ with $pr_\hat Y(x,y,t)=(y,t)$.
Finally define $H:(X\times Y)\times [0,1]\to X\times Y$ with $H=(H_1\circ pr_\hat Y,\ H_2\circ pr_\hat X)$
so that $H(x,y,0)=(\mathrm{id}_X,\mathrm{id}_Y)(x,y)=(x,y)$ for all $x∈X$ and $y\in Y$,
 and $H(x,y,1)=(c_{x},c_{y})(x,y)=(x_0,y_0)$ for all $x∈X$ and $y\in Y$,

then we have $(\mathrm{id}_{X},\mathrm{id}_{Y})\simeq (c_{x},c_{y}) $
Note that $H_1,H_2,pr_\hat X,pr_\hat Y$ are continuous, then $H_1\circ pr_\hat Y$ and $H_2\circ pr_\hat X$ are continuous too
Thus $H$ is continuous.

Comment: Just a nitpick: $H(x,y,0) = (\operatorname{id}_X,\operatorname{id}_Y)(x,y) = (x,y)$, while $H(0) = (\operatorname{id}_X,\operatorname{id}_Y)$.

Comment: How do you know the product of two homotopies is a homotopy?

Comment: No. $H_1^{-1}(A)\times H_2^{-1}(B)$ would be a subset of $X\times I\times Y\times I$, but you want a subset of $X\times Y\times I$. Use this argument instead: A map into a product space is continuous iff its projections onto the factors are continuous. So here you have to prove that the compositions with the projections can be decomposed $X\times Y\times I\to X\times I\to X$ and that these maps are continuous.

Comment: You have $H:X\times Y\times I\to X\times Y$. Composing with the projection onto $X$ gives $X\times Y\times I\to X\times I\to X$, where the first map maps $(x,y,t)$ to $(x,t)$ and the second map is $H_1$. But this is just the map that you defined yourself, and this decomposition shows that it is continous.

Comment: Why did you change your answer?

Comment: Your old answer was nearly correct. If $pr_\hat Y$ denotes the map $X\times Y\times I\to X\times I$ which simply omits the $Y$-coordinate, then $H=H_1\circ pr_\hat Y\times H_2\circ pr_\hat X$ would be correct.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant the map with a comma instead of a $\times$.